# Top align a div

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have a div element containing radio buttons and canvas elements. How do I get this so the radio buttons are aligned with the top of the canvas elements?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: auto;
      max-width: 450px;
      font-family: "Arial";
      font-weight: 200;
      font-size: 22px;
    }
  }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    1) <span id="q1Text">**********</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1Opt1">
    <canvas id="q1Opt1Canvas" width="120" height="120" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1Opt2">
    <canvas id="q1Opt2Canvas" width="120" height="120" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1Opt3">
    <canvas id="q1Opt3Canvas" width="120" height="120" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
  </div>
  <br>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
div/*add a class here preferabily*/ input{
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

***[jsBin](http://jsbin.com/zeneju/1/edit?html,css,js,output)***

Answer (score 1):

Considering adding a class to your input tag example:

```
 <input class="ql" type="radio" name="q1" id="q1Opt1">
```

And apply vertical alignment position using the following CSS

```
.ql {
     vertical-align: top;
 }
```

Working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/5u2w4gs6/

You can learn more about vertical-align property on [this interesting article](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/v/vertical-align/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want them aligned to the top, use:

```
radio { vertical-align: top; }
```

And if you want them centered, add

```
margin-top: 60px; // 60= canevas height / 2
```